# C++ read from file only when there is more content

Tags: c++

How can I check if there is more content in a text file in c++ and if there is continue to read it?
I am trying to read a some words from a text file but the number of words is not specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24607385/read-data-from-fstream) here.

Also, std:: is a reference to the namespace of code you are calling. When you include a file that is in the standard libraries, such as string, vector, fstream, iostream, you need to either declare that your file will use the namespace std with using namespace std; OR you append std:: to the method or variable.

Comment: I did but I am not familiar with std:: notation. Can you please help me?

Comment: std:: is a reference to the namespace of code you are calling. When you include a file that is in the standard libraries, such as string, vector, fstream, iostream, you need to either declare that your file will use the namespace std with using namespace std; OR you append std:: to the method or variable.

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::vector` and `std::string`.  Use a correct form of reading a file:

```
std::string word;
std::vector<std::string> word_database;
while (text_file >> word)
{
  word_database.push_back(word);
}
std::cout << "Words read: " << word_database.size() << "\n";
```

Comment: Unofortunately I am not familiar with std:: notation. Can you please help me?

Comment: Read your favorite reference about "namespaces".  Remove the `std::` notation if it bothers you.

Comment: 'std' is the namespace in which nearly all of C++ standard library functions are implemented. By '::' you 'look' into that namespace and specify a type or function within it. see [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/program_structure/)